# Solution for Error 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, connection-string

I have published my website http://www.theyuvaworld.com for my college project but it is showing

```
Error 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified. Other things are working properly.
```

You can visit website for detailed Error.

My project is `C# ASP.NET 4.0` and built in `Sql Server 2008`  of Visual Studio 2010.

I am using this connection string in every page.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
```

I know I can put it in `Web.config` but I don't know how to use it in aspx pages for queries?

My Question is : What changes should I do in my Connection String to get my website working.

Other details : I have taken my Web Hosting Plan from http://www.hostingfarms.in and it supports Sql Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to work around this piece of code .Username and password should be supplied in get connection string if you are using sql authentication**

```
private static void OpenSqlConnection()
{
    string connectionString = GetConnectionString();

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

        connection.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("State: {0}", connection.State);
        Console.WriteLine("ConnectionString: {0}",
            connection.ConnectionString);
    }
}

static private string GetConnectionString()
{
    // To avoid storing the connection string in your code, 
    // you can retrieve it from a configuration file.
    return "Data Source=MSSQL1;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;"
        + "Integrated Security=true;";
}
```

Comment: I am new to .Net. I just wanted to know that

What changes should I do in my Connection String to get my website working?

Comment: why are you using AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf. If your DB exists in your sql instance why dont you use database name.  Data Source=Your_Server_Name;Initial Catalog= Your_Database_Name;UserId=Your_Username;Password=Your_Password

Comment: Because my hosting service provider told me to do so, Can you give me a e.g of connection string?

Comment: Maybe ask your hosting provider for an example of the connection string. If you're on shared hosting the database server will normally be on a separate machine.